# Bind json data to telerik dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu, telerik

I have telerik dropdownlist

```
@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("InstrumentType").BindTo(Model.MITypesList).Enable(!Model.IsReadOnlyOtherProperties).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "instrument-type" }))
```

left I have button add('add-type-mi') which save to db by ajax

```
$(".add-type-mi").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var choiсeMi = $("#choiсe-type-mi");
            choiсeMi.find(".btnSubmit").one("click", function () {
                var nameId = choiсeMi.find(".className").attr('id');
                var nameType = choiсeMi.find(".className").val();

                var categoryId = choiсeMi.find(".classCategory").attr('id');
                var categoryName = choiсeMi.find(".classCategory").val();

                var strVal = [{ name: nameId, value: nameType }, { name: categoryId, value: categoryName }];

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $('#saveType').data('save-type'),
                    data: { "stringValues": JSON.stringify(strVal), "tableValues": [] },
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                    //this I need to bind data.title to dropdownlist
                        choiсeMi.data('tWindow').close();

                    }
                });
            });

            choiсeMi.find(".btnCancel").one("click", function () {
                choiсeMi.data('tWindow').close();
            });

            choiсeMi.data('tWindow').center().open();
        });
```

I need bind my data to dropdownlist('InstrumentType') without update page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to bind json I use dataBind()
there is my code after success: function

```
var instrumentTypeList = $("#InstrumentType").data("tDropDownList");

        var arrayList = instrumentTypeList.data;
        if (arrayList == undefined) {
            arrayList = [];
        }

            arrayList.push({ Text: data.objFullName, Value: data.id });
            instrumentTypeList.dataBind(arrayList);
```